# iptables as proxy server for IoT devices similar to socat

Tags: iptables, amazon-ec2, proxy, socat

I am able to forward incoming TCP traffic from IoT devices hitting a port towards another destination server using socat using this command

`socat TCP-LISTEN:5050,reuseaddr,fork TCP:some-random-host-in-another-network.com:5035`

where **some-random-host-in-another-network.com** is the destination server IP. The only thing I want to change is for the destination server to see the traffic coming in from the gateway server, not from the IP of the actual IoT devices

Considering IP tables handles this on a kernal level, how do I handle this? I have already tried using below commands but it does not work with IPtables. I am hosting ubuntu instance on EC2 with port 5050 allowed for incoming through security groups and getting packets on tcpdump.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5050 -j DNAT --to-destination some-random-host-in-another-network.com:5035
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d some-random-host-in-another-network.com -p tcp --dport 5035 -j MASQUERADE
```

Please help me out that how will iptables be set to allow multiple connection on the server and transmit the data to the destination server only changing the IP seen by the destination server as of the instance/gateway server.